# What is this string encoded in?

Tags: string, format, encode

I have a string I am trying to figure out, but I have no idea what format it is in. Any ideas? Here is the string

5365616e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's regular hexadecimal encoding.

You can find a conversion chart on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), use any of a multitude of [online converters](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html), or use a command-line tool to convert, e.g. `echo -ne '5365616e' | xxd -r -p`.

The converted string is `Sean`.